# Custom Font Doesn't Load when testing iOS app

Tags: ios, xcode

I'm trying to use custom fonts on my iOS app and imported and loaded all the custom fonts I want to use in my info.plist file. The fonts appear to be loading properly in my main.storyboard file, however when I test my app on either the simulator or my own device, the fonts don't load properly and default to built-in fonts.

My main.storyboard versus my simulation:

[image: My main.storyboard versus my simulation]

How can I fix this error?

I tried adding the key "Application fonts resource path" with an empty value to my info.plist but that didn't seem to work.

[image: my info.plist file]